# Relative probabilities using random number gen

Tags: random, probability

If I have relative probabilities of events A, B, C occurring.

i.e P(A) = 0.45, P(B) = 0.35, P(C) = 0.20,

How do I do represent this using a random number generator between 0 and 1?

i.e. R = rand(0,1)

```
if (R < 0.45)
   event A

else if(R < 0.35)
  event B

else if(R < 0.20)
  event C
```

The above works for two events A,B but I think the above is wrong for three or more since there is overlapping.

This is obviously a very simple question and the answer should be immediately evident, but I'm just too stupid to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add the probabilities together. I'm showing explicit `if/then` statements, but it's easy to do this with probabilities in an array with a loop, so it can be very dynamic. Note that the ordering doesn't matter.

```
if (R < 0.45)
   event A

else if(R < 0.45 + 0.35) // R < 0.80
  event B

else // (R must necessarily be < 0.45 + 0.35 + 0.20, or 1) 
  event C
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have below conditions:

```
if(R < 0.45)
    Event A
else if(R < 0.80)
    Event B
else
    Event C
```